# Icon Suggesting Accessibility Functionality

Tags: icons, accessibility, contrast

I'm building an 'accessibility bar' that will include functions such as; increase/decrease contrast, text-size, line-spacing etc.

Is there a default, standard, recommended or well known icon that could be used to show/hide this functionality?

I feel like the 'wheelchair' icon: [wheelchair accessibility icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkF86.png) doesn't represent web accessibility very well..

Can someone suggest any widely adopted alternatives? What would you use?

Answer (score 1):

You want an icon associated with some action that will unhide the toolbar?  There isn't really a common icon for that.  I agree that you should stay away from the wheelchair.  I sometimes have to bump up my font size or increase contrast, especially in very bright areas, like outside in the sun, but I wouldn't look for such a feature under a wheelchair icon because I don't associate myself with that.

The Mac has an "Accessibility" or "Universal Access" icon in system preferences.  It looks like a person with its arms outstretched.

The PC has "Ease of Access" icon in the control panel.  I'm not sure how to describe it.  Kind of a pie with 8 pieces, but the two pieces in the north-east corner are missing and are replaced with a down and right arrow forming a right angle.

Neither icon conveys accessibility to me.  It's just a symbol you have to learn (if you have vision).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input! The 'Universal Access' icon looks like a promising alternative.

However, we've also had the opportunity to discuss this issue with an accessibility expert, and simply using a commonly accepted 'preferences' or 'settings' icon could probably be sufficient in this case.

Like you pointed out, these settings are useful to anyone, not just disabled users.

Comment: That's a great solution and would be what I would recommend too, being an accessibility expert myself :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you need to go with the wheelchair symbol if you need a specific symbol. 
But put that in a textual context too.

Like:
"Accessibility features" + Symbol

The wheelchair is not a fresh symbol, but as most people with disabilities agree on is that it's universal and wellknown. Taking the accessibility symbols in Mac or Windows is not to recommend.

As suggested a settings icon would be an option, but it depends on the context of the site itself. Will it interfere with other icons? To avoid confusion, always accompany the icon with text, never rely on visual icons to tell the whole purpose of interaction.